# A vector as a patchwork of two other vectors

Tags: c++, performance, loops, vector, iterator

**Subset a vector**

Below is the benchmark of two different solutions to subset a vector

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
           struct timeval timeStart,
                    timeEnd;

           // Build the vector 'whole' to subset
           vector<int> whole;
           for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000  ; i++)
           {
              whole.push_back(i);
           }

           // Solution 1 - Use a for loops
           gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
           vector<int> subset1;
           subset1.reserve(9123000 - 1200);
           for (int i = 1200 ; i < 9123000 ; i++)
           {
               subset1.push_back(i);
           }
           gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);

           cout << "Solution 1 took " << ((timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec) * 1000000 + timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec) << " us"  << endl;

           // Solution 2 - Use iterators and constructor
           gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
           vector<int>::iterator first = whole.begin() + 1200;
           vector<int>::iterator last =  whole.begin() + 9123000;
           vector<int> subset2(first, last);
           gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);

           cout << "Solution 2 took " << ((timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec) * 1000000 + timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec) << " us"  << endl;
 }
```

On my old laptop, it outputs

```
Solution 1 took 243564 us
Solution 2 took 164220 us
```

Clearly solution 2 is faster.

**Make a patchwork of two vectors**

I would like to create a vector as a patchwork of two different vectors of the same size. The vector starts as one and then takes the value of the other and back and forth. I guess I don't fully understand how to copy values to a vector by using iterator pointing to elements in another vector. The only implementation I can think of requires using an analogous to solution 1 above. Something like...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  // input 
  vector<int> breakpoints = {2, 5, 7, INT_MAX};
  vector<int> v1 = { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9 };
  vector<int> v2 = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };

  // Create output
  vector<int> ExpectedOutput;
  ExpectedOutput.reserve(v1.size());
  int origin = 0;
  int breakpoints_index = 0;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < v1.size() ; i++)
  {
     if (origin)
     {
        ExpectedOutput.push_back(v1[i]);
     } else
     {
        ExpectedOutput.push_back(v2[i]);
     }
     if (breakpoints[breakpoints_index] == i)
     {
        origin = !origin;
        breakpoints_index++;
     }
  }


  // print output
  cout << "output: ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < ExpectedOutput.size() ; i++)
  {
     cout << ExpectedOutput[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
output: 10 20 30 4 5 6 70 80 9
```

It feels like there must be a better solution such as something analogous to Solution 2 from above. Is there a faster solution?

Comment: I suspect solution 2 is so much faster because the compiler manages to optimize it down to a single `memcpy` call (or equivalent in machine code). No amount of cleverness could do the same for the task of interleaving contents of two vectors.

Comment: Oh....so I guess that as the "chunks" of the two source vectors becomes big enough, it would become beneficial to make a single `memcpy` (I did not know that function before reading your comment) call for each chunk rather than copying each element (each `int` in the example) separately, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating `push_back()` means that every time around the loop, a check is being performed to ensure `capacity()` is large enough (if not, then more space must be reserved).  When you copy a whole range, only one `capacity()` check needs to be done.

You can still be a bit smarter with your interleaving by copying chunks.  Here's the very basic idea:

```
int from = 0;
for( int b : breakpoints )
{
    std::swap( v1, v2 );
    int to = 1 + std::min( b, static_cast<int>( v1.size() ) - 1 );
    ExpectedOutput.insert( ExpectedOutput.end(), v1.begin() + from, v1.begin() + to );
    from = to;
}
```

For the sake of brevity, this code actually swaps `v1` and `v2` and so always operates on `v1`.  I did the swap *before* the insert, to emulate the logic in your code (which is acting on `v2` first).  You can do this in a non-modifying way instead if you want.

Of course, you can see a bit more is going on in this code.  It would only make sense if you have considerably fewer breakpoints than values.  Note that it also assumes `v1` and `v2` are the same length.